# Opening a file, Writer complains "unable to lock file"

Tags: libreoffice, lock

Using Windows 10 I had to change my user with one that uses Active Directory (AD), meaning I got a new SID and `%userprofile%` path.
After copying and adjusting hopefully all files, settings, and some ACLs, I have a problem that LibreOffice Writer complains being unable to lock a file (like "*file is locked for editing by unknown user*"), suggesting to open it read-only, or to open a copy of the file.
When I try to edit a copy, Writer complains "*Write error. Could not write file*".

I have no idea where the problem could be (the error details are quite poor), so I checked these already:

- Directory and file owned by current SID with full access
- I can create a copy of the file in question in the same directory
- Other files have the same problem

What else could I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem and the solution:
`%appdata%\LibreOffice\4\user\registrymodifications.xcu` contains a list of recently opened documents (and possibly other paths).
After replacing all occurrences of "`C:\Users\`*old_username*" with "`C:\Users\`*new_username*", I could open the file without complaint.

(This solution was inspired by https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/75637/problem-with-locked-odt-files/)